# scrapy how to crawl text from a subpage of the start url

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to write a spider that extracts text from a link on my start url, but i dont know how I redirect my spider to the link
I tried this:

```
    def parse(self, response):

        sel = response.xpath("/html/body/main/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/article/h2/a")
        print(sel.xpath("//html/body/main/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[1]/text()")).extract()
        pass
```

But it doesnt work(doesnt print the text) 
Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

This is the path to the link on my Start URL

```
//html/body/main/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/article/h2/a
```

And this is the paragraph I want to print

```
//html/body/main/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[1]/text()
```

Comment: If you don't give us an example `response`, we can't really help :)

Comment: There is no output, thats my problem

Comment: A 'sub-page' is simply another page whose url is obtained from a 'previous' page. You must make a second request to the sub-page (its url should be in the variable `sel`) and use xpath on the (2nd) response.

`sel` is a string. Print it to debug.

Comment: Okay so I printed sel and it printed the URL of the page. What do you mean with second request though? Im sorry if this sounds stupid im very new in that stuff